# What's the deal with Gnarlak's fingers?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

At one point in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, Newt Scamander winds up having to make a deal with a goblin named Gnarlak, played by Ron Perlman. Below is an image of Gnarlak from that scene.

[image: Gnarlack and his gross fingers]

As you can see (most obviously on the hand holding the cigar, but also on the hand holding his drink), Gnarlak's fingers are all bent out of shape, curling back on themselves and nearly touching the back of his hand. It's... gross, and very noticeable throughout the scenes that Gnarlack is in, and yet no one in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* makes any reference to his unusual fingers.

So why are Gnarlak's fingers like this?

Comment: I didn't notice this at all…

Comment: Take it easy man! He's very sensitive about his fingers!

Comment: Nothing in the script; he's a gangster, perhaps someone broke them?

Comment: @Fatalize really? That was the only thing I could look at during that scene (after realizing it was Ron Perlman and grinning like an idiot).

Comment: @FlorianPeschka - I didn't even realize it was Perlman until someone mentioned his name in the credits. *That's* how distracting the backwards fingers were.

Comment: Bad motion capture?

Comment: @fabriced I'm pretty sure that something as obvious as that wouldn't have slipped through the cracks of a major production.

Comment: Perhaps it's goblin arthritis. It ended his career playing piano in this very club.

Comment: I originally thought that maybe it was a reference to a bad goblin puppet from an earlier film (like CGI Yoda's wobbly ears), but all the screenshots I've found show relatively  normal-looking fingers.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - Deleted stuff from the Rowling's script, but apparently survived into filming. See my answer (with freehand circles).

Answer (score 11):

### It's the remnants of a deleted plot element, and may have been related to Goblin cursed treasure.

Although not in the finished movie, Gnarlack's fingers were briefly mentioned in a page from Rowling's *original* screenplay<sup>1</sup> which [has appeared](http://jkrowling.com/wp-content/themes/jkrowling/assets/images/script.png) on Rowling's new website.

> [image: picture of screenplay (transcription below)]
>
> The Goblin owner of the Blind Pig, Gnarlack, is moving through the bar, tea-towel over his shoulder, cigar in mouth, **many of his fingers bent back on themselves, useless.**

None of the released materials have directly explained why this is the case, but there is this additional line about Gnarlak's backstory that may be alluding to it.

> [image: picture of screenplay (transcription below)]
>
> **Gnarlak**: British, huh? Yeah, I'm from the old country myself. Yeah, my whole family's with Gringotts Wizarding Bank, yeah, dey's all in **the treasure-and-curse business**.

---

<sup>1. Not to be confused with "*The Original Screenplay*" - the published version which was heavily edited to match the whims of the directors, producers, cast, and test audiences.</sup>

Comment: Although interesting, this doesn't answer the question asked

Comment: @Valorum "*yet no one in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them makes any reference to his unusual fingers*"

Comment: Indeed, and this would make a wonderful comment.

Comment: @Valorum - *What's the deal with his fingers?* This is covered in my first quote. *Why are Gnarlak's fingers like this?* This is possibly covered in my second quote.

Comment: I can only go on my own impressions. If I'd spotted this, I wouldn't have based an answer on it.

Comment: @Valorum - I was on the fence about it, but I don't think that my partial answer will be deterring other answers, and the question deserves much better answers than the ones it's previously gotten. (Also, comments don't allow for free-hand circles.)

Comment: Ah well, if it's got freehand circles then it must be good.

Comment: The images here are already captioned. Alt text that doesn't add anything shouldn't be used.

Comment: Images that are already captioned should then either have entirely blank alt text or alt text that makes it clear that there's a transcription. Leaving it as "enter image description here" gives no indication of what the image is or whether it contains information not contained in the text of the post.

Comment: @Mithical - I myself don't care to add alt text. If you want to add *correct* alt text go and knock yourself out, I don't care. But replacing my incorrect and useless alt text with other equally incorrect and useless alt text is the very definition of a frivolous and unnecessary edit and I will revert those edits on sight. That's like changing a misspelled word to a different misspelled word. That's not what the edit button is for.

Comment: Please see the [guidelines for alt text](https://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#complex). Even if an alternative is provided - in this case, the quoted text - there should still be a succinct indication of what the image is. In this case, communicating that the text is available immediately below is better than leaving it as a mystery for anyone relying on alt text (screen readers, images blocked, etc.).